# The navigation property 'FootballGame' was not found on the dependent type 'Bd.Domain.Entities.FootballGame'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am creating my first asp.net mvc3 application. I'm using code first methodology. I have the following models:

```
public class FootballGame
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id_FootballGame { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FootballGame")]
    public Guid? FK_id_FootballGame { get; set; }
    public virtual FootballGame PreviousFootballGame { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FootballTeam")]
    public Guid id_FootballTeam_owner { get; set; }
    public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeamOwner { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("FootballTeam")]
    public Guid id_FootballTeam_guest { get; set; }
    public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeamGuest { get; set; }
}

public class FootballTeam
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id_FootballTeam { get; set; }
    public string teamName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following class:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext() : base("name=EFDbContext") { }

    public DbSet<FootballTeam> FootballTeams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FootballGame> FootballGames { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is an exception:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'FK_id_FootballGame' on type
>   'Bd.Domain.FootballGame' is not valid. The navigation
>   property 'FootballGame' was not found on the dependent type
>   'Bd.Domain.FootballGame'. The Name value should be a valid
>   navigation property name.

I tried to remove these lines:

```
[ForeignKey("FootballGame")]
public virtual FootballGame PreviousFootballGame { get; set; }
```

However, another exception to appear:

> The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'id_FootballTeam_owner' on type
>   'Bd.FootballGame' is not valid. The navigation property 'FootballTeam'
>   was not found on the dependent type 'Bd.FootballGame'. The Name value
>   should be a valid navigation property name.

I look forward to any help. 
Regards, Denis.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class FootballGame
{
    [Key]
    public Guid id_FootballGame { get; set; }

    public Guid? FK_id_FootballGame { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FK_id_FootballGame")]
    public virtual FootballGame PreviousFootballGame { get; set; }

    public Guid id_FootballTeam_owner { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_FootballTeam_owner")]
    public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeamOwner { get; set; }

    public Guid id_FootballTeam_guest { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id_FootballTeam_guest")]
    public virtual FootballTeam FootballTeamGuest { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and mine too.. Thank u.

Comment: I don't understand: do the virtual property have to exist as db table columns? I get following error when setting virtual "fake" properties:
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Category' cannot be configured as a navigation property. The property must be a valid entity type and the property should have a non-abstract getter and setter.