# Entity Framework can't create foreign key constraint, "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table..."

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a one-to-many relationship between two models, File and AMCN. Here's my File:

```
public class File
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AmcnId { get; set; }
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }

    public virtual AMCN Amcn { get; set; }
}
```

Here's part of my AMCN:

```
public class AMCN
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    //lots of other data here...
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<FoSL> FoSLs { get; set; }
}
```

so I went into the package manager console, did `add-migration files`, which worked and generated this:

```
public partial class files : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Files",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    AmcnId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    FileName = c.String(maxLength: 255),
                    ContentType = c.String(maxLength: 100),
                    Content = c.Binary(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AMCNs", t => t.AmcnId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AmcnId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Files", "AmcnId", "dbo.AMCNs");
        DropIndex("dbo.Files", new[] { "AmcnId" });
        DropTable("dbo.Files");
    }
}
```

but when I do `update-database` I get an error:

```
Error Number:1776,State:0,Class:16
There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'dbo.AMCNs' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_dbo.Files_dbo.AMCNs_AmcnId'.
Could not create constraint. See previous errors.
```

As far as I know, entity framework should be able to figure out that I want AmcnId to be a foreign key pointing to AMCN.Id. In fact, when I made another class, FoSL, it worked fine.

```
public class FoSL
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int AmcnId { get; set; }
    public string FO { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
}
```

generated migration class

```
public partial class FoSL : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.FoSLs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    AmcnId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    FO = c.String(),
                    StartDate = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Location = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AMCNs", t => t.AmcnId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .Index(t => t.AmcnId);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.FoSLs", "AmcnId", "dbo.AMCNs");
        DropIndex("dbo.FoSLs", new[] { "AmcnId" });
        DropTable("dbo.FoSLs");
    }
}
```

I can't see any real difference between the `FoSL` and `File` classes, or their migrations. As far as I know, this should work. So what am I doing wrong?

I've tried adding `[Key]` on `AMCN.Id`, didn't help.

edit: the initial dbmigration included this for `Up()`:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.AMCNs",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    Created = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    //lots of other data here....
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);
```

Comment: If you not use FLuent API configuration , you have to use properly ef code first conventions name.

Comment: where is migration class for "AMCN" which is causing error, your error says AMCN table does not have a primary key.. check that code first

Comment: @KarthikGanesan edited question to include it, M.Wiśnicki aren't I?

Comment: Maybe remove lazy loading before the instruction that generate the error ? Just in case

Comment: @AntoinePelletier how do I do that? I always thought EF Builds its model entirely before trying anything with the database.

Comment: If you can instanciate your db context like : `MyEntities db = new MyEntities();`  Then `db.LazyLoadingEnabled =  false` do it before any Linq query

Comment: @AntoinePelletier I see. But I'm getting this error when trying update-database in the package manager console, my program isn't actually running.

Comment: Migration will update db before context creation, lazy leading have nothing related to that issue

Comment: Right, sorry...

Comment: type this arrtibute on AmcnId of File class [ForeignKey("AMCN")

Comment: @KarthikGanesan got error: `The ForeignKeyAttribute on property 'AmcnId' on type 'ManufacturingChangeNotice.Models.File' is not valid. The navigation property 'AMCN' was not found on the dependent type 'ManufacturingChangeNotice.Models.File'. The Name value should be a valid navigation property name.`

Comment: Also, tried it lowercase. Add-migration worked as before, but I get the same error when trying `update-database`; "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table..."

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15032656/the-navigation-property-footballgame-was-not-found-on-the-dependent-type-bd-d

Comment: Given that link I tried putting `[ForeignKey("AmcnId")]` on `File.Amcn`, same error on `update-database`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the culprit was something I'd forgotten about; I made a backup database for testing so I wouldn't affect the production database until I'm ready. However, when I backed up the data into a new database, it didn't take the keys with it. So my AMCN table in the database didn't have the primary key that entity framework expected it to have. I added a primary key, ran `update-database` in the package manager console again, and it worked fine.

(not sure if I should delete this question...)

Comment: Well if you consider that it won't help anyone because the question is just about a mistake you've made, maybe you should, but i'm not a moderator

Answer (score 0):

The exact same thing that happened to Adam happened to me. I had created a backup database for testing changes without affecting my production environment. Using the SQL Import/Export Wizard on MS SSMS to make a copy, meant that the PK information for the tables hadn't been copied across, hence the Migration working, but trying to update the DB did not, as no explicit PK could be found.

Manually configured the PK in SSMS Table Designer and the Migration worked perfectly. Posting in case someone makes the same mistake I did!